# Check and Uncheck logic between Parent item and child items in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, web-frontend, nested-object

**In React JS, I'm facing the issue that all model children are selected when i click the Brand.
If I uncheck the Brand, all model children are going to hide.
Help me to write a logic that Ex:- If I check Hyundai, then Hyundai car models has to be show and checked only. If I uncheck the any one of the Hyundai model, then the Hyundai has to be uncheck.**

**Data should like this:**

```
[
  {
    display: "HYUNDAI",
    status: false,
    filter: {
      key: "make",
      value: "hyundai",
    },
    count: 292,
    children: [
      {
        display: "Grand i10",
        status: false,
        filter: {
          key: "model",
          value: "grand i10",
        },
        count: 81,
      },
      {
        display: "CRETA",
        status: false,
        filter: {
          key: "model",
          value: "creta",
        },
        count: 47,
      },
      {
        display: "Elite i20",
        status: false,
        filter: {
          key: "model",
          value: "elite i20",
        },
        count: 44,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import carData from './data.json';

const App = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(carData)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => setData(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
}, []);

return (
  <div>
   
    <h1>Car Brands and it's Models</h1>
    {data.map((el) => {
      return (
        <div className="data">
          <table className="table">
            <tc>
              <th>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="checkbox"
                  value={check}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setCheck(!check);
                  }}
                />
                {el.display}
              </th>
            </tc>
            {check && (
              <div className="datas">
                {el.children.map((ele, innerIndex) => (
                  <div key={innerIndex}>
                    <tc>
                      <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" checked />
                        {ele.display}
                      </td>
                    </tc>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Please put the data example into a block of code so people can actually read it. Also provide us your revelant code so we can help.

Comment: Kept the code which i'm facing the issue.

Comment: Do you want the brand to show even when one of the children model gets unchecked? If that is the case then you need to move the display of children models to be a serparate component.

Comment: If i check the brand, then the brand and it's models should be checked and it should be display on the bottom of the brand. 
If i uncheck any of the brand model, then brand should get uncheck.
If i uncheck the brand, then all models should not be display and it should be hide like toggle.

Comment: I understand, but i mean to ask if i unchecked a model while brand is checked (all models are checked and displayed) does brand get unchecked but still display the models?

Comment: Yes. If you uncheck any of the model for the particular brand, brand should get uncheck and models should be display on the bottom of the brand.

Comment: If that is the case then you can move out the display of each brand to be a smaller component, so they can have their own display state instead of relying on the check state of all brand.

Comment: how to write a code for that?

Comment: I already gave you the idea, you should try it out. But ok, i'll make an update to my answer.

Comment: Ok. I'm working on that...I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: You can move the display of the brands/models out and make it a smaller component. I'll try to make the least change possible to your code.

App:

```
const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(carData)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => setData(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Car Brands and it's Models</h1>
            {data.map((el) => {
                <Brand data={el} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Brand:

```
const Brand = ({ data }) => {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleCheck = () => {
        setCheck(!check);
        setShow(!check);
    };

    return (
        <div className="data">
            <table className="table">
                <tc>
                    <th>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            className="checkbox"
                            value={check}
                            onClick={handleCheck}
                        />
                        {data.display}
                    </th>
                </tc>
                {show && (
                    <div className="datas">
                        {data.children.map((ele, innerIndex) => (
                            <Models
                                data={ele}
                                BrandCheck={check}
                                BrandShow={show}
                                setBrandCheck={setCheck}
                                key={innerIndex}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Models:

```
const Models = ({ data, BrandCheck, BrandShow, setBrandCheck }) => {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
    const handleCheck = () => {
        if (check) setBrandCheck(false);
        setCheck(!check);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (BrandCheck) setCheck(true);
        if (!BrandShow) setCheck(false);
    }, [BrandCheck, BrandShow]);
    return (
        <div>
            <tc>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="checkbox"
                        checked
                        value={check}
                        onClick={handleCheck}
                    />
                    {data.display}
                </td>
            </tc>
        </div>
    );
};
```